# Ошибка при создании объекта сокета в boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Пытаюсь создать объект сокета. Появляется такая ошибка:

> call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or
>   conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

Код:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;

void DataManager::ConnectToSocket(string ip, int port) {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    socket(ios);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: Создание сокета происходит не в строчке `socket(ios);`. Это выражение пытается вызвать у уже созданного объекта `operator()`. Т.к. он не определён, вы получаете соответствующее сообщение. Думаю, вам надо сделать сокет членом класса DataManager и в его конструкторе вызывать конструктор сокета с параметром `boost::asio::io_service`

Comment: @cppquestions, а как тогда можно создать объект сокета, чтобы его можно было в 1 методе подключить, а в другом, к примеру, туда слать что-нибудь?

Comment: Ну я же написал - сделать членом класса DataManager